# Ejecutar consulta de C# en SqlServer

Tags: c#, sql-server

Requiero ejecutar en SQLServer una consulta hecha en C#, la siguiente es la consulta que tengo hecha en C#

```
var query = (from tblTicket in db.TK_HD_TICKETS
               join tblRecord in db.TK_DT_RECORDS on tblTicket.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID equals tblRecord.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
               join tblEmployee in db.TK_BT_EMPLOYEES on tblRecord.TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID equals tblEmployee
                   .TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID into tempEmplo
               join tblServices in db.TK_CT_SERVICES on tblRecord.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID equals tblServices
                   .TK_CT_SERVICES_ID
               join tblPriorities in db.TK_CT_PRIORITIES on tblRecord.TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID equals tblPriorities
                   .TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID
               join tblSubservices in db.TK_CT_SUBSERVICES on tblRecord.TK_CT_SUBSERVICES_ID equals tblSubservices
                   .TK_CT_SUBSERVICES_ID
               join tblSLAS in db.TK_BT_SLAS on new
                       {tblRecord.TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID, tblSubservices.TK_CT_SUBSERVICES_ID} equals
                   new {tblSLAS.TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID, tblSLAS.TK_CT_SUBSERVICES_ID}
               join tblStatus in db.TK_CT_STATUS on tblRecord.TK_CT_STATUS_ID equals tblStatus.TK_CT_STATUS_ID
               from tblEmployee in tempEmplo.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where tblRecord.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID == (
                         from tblTicketAux in db.TK_HD_TICKETS
                         join tblRecordAux in db.TK_DT_RECORDS on tblTicketAux.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID equals tblRecordAux
                             .TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
                         where tblTicket.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID == tblTicketAux.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
                         select tblRecordAux.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID
                     ).Max()
```

Estuve realizando algunas modificaciones en la consulta y esto es lo que llevo hasta el momento

```
SELECT * from TK_HD_TICKETS
               INNER join TK_DT_RECORDS on TK_HD_TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID= TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
               INNER join TK_BT_EMPLOYEES on TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID=TK_BT_EMPLOYEES.TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID --into tempEmplo
               INNER join TK_CT_SERVICES on TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID=TK_CT_SERVICES.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID
               INNER join TK_CT_PRIORITIES on TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID=TK_CT_PRIORITIES.TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID
               INNER join TK_CT_SUBSERVICES on TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_CT_SUBSERVICES_ID=TK_CT_SUBSERVICES.TK_CT_SUBSERVICES_ID
               INNER join TK_BT_SLAS on
              
                      (TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID, TK_CT_SUBSERVICES.TK_CT_SUBSERVICES_ID) =
                  (TK_BT_SLAS.TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID, TK_BT_SLAS.TK_CT_SUBSERVICES_ID)


              INNER join TK_CT_STATUS on TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_CT_STATUS_ID=TK_CT_STATUS.TK_CT_STATUS_ID
             from TK_BT_EMPLOYEES) --in tempEmplo.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID
                         from tblTicketAux in db.TK_HD_TICKETS
                         join tblRecordAux in db.TK_DT_RECORDS on TK_HD_TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID=TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
                         where TK_HD_TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID=TK_HD_TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
                        select TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID
                     ).Max()
```

Los primeros 5 joins están bien solo que tuve problemas a partir del `new` en la consulta en C#, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar a terminarla correctamente.

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: Saludos. En SQL esos `new` no existen (hasta donde llevo, no soy DBA o similar); debes realizar la comparación de cada campo usando el `AND` el último `INNER JOIN` por lo que veo debe ser un `LEFT JOIN` realmente. Desde luego el `Max()` igual deberás modificarlo por que no va (por lo menos allí y de esa forma no).

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes hacerlo, te recomiendo que pruebes con https://www.linqpad.net/ , la version **gratuita** puede traducir consultas como esta a sintaxis SQL. (Aparte de hacer muchas otras cosas.)

Es muy facil de usar:

1. Agregas la conexión a la DB.
2. Pegas el código de EF
3. Ejecutas
4. Cambias al tab de SQL para ver la consulta que genera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]